# Sudo apt-get update command is getting error

Tags: apt, 15.10, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and 64-bit system.

I am new to Ubuntu I am trying to use `sudo apt-get update` but I am getting error I am not able to understand what is wrong and I don't know how to rectify that error.

Below is my error after using the command.

```
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [6,431 B]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages [255 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages [20.4 kB]
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources [3,560 B]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted amd64 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe amd64 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [107 kB]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en              
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en [2,501 B]
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources [60.5 kB]  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Fetched 32.1 MB in 4min 59s (107 kB/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo apt-get update
```

or:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf

sudo apt-get update
```

If it still doesn't work, try to change your `Download from` server in `Softwares and Updates` of Ubuntu. May be give `Main Server` a try.

One reason can be a proxy blocking compression .gz files which can cause apt-get update to return the mismatch.

I hope it helps.

Comment: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

Comment: I am getting 2 error which i have posted above

Comment: have you tried:
`sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo apt-get update` afterwards?

Comment: yes i did and i get same error for both command

Comment: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems